# How can I get Coronavirus-related articles using the New York Times API?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

I want to get the headlines and the comments from New York Times articles related to the Coronavirus using the NYT API so I can apply NLP techniques like Sentiment.

I want to get the articles that are featured here: https://www.nytimes.com/news-event/coronavirus

How can I filter my query URL to get these articles?

My requestURL right now is (Article Search API using Python):

```
def getHeadlines():
    begin_date = 20210301
    end_date = 20210331
    key = '******'
    requestUrl = "https://api.nytimes.com/svc/search/v2/articlesearch.json?begin_date={}&end_date={}&facet=false&facet_filter=false&fl=web_url%2C%20headline%2C%20pub_date&fq=subject%3A(%22Coronavirus%20(2019-nCoV)%22%20%22Disease%20Rates%22%20%22Deaths%20(Obituaries)%22%20%22Vaccination%20and%20Immunization%22%20%22Drugstores%22)%20&sort=oldest&api-key={}".format(begin_date, end_date, key)
    requestHeaders = {
        "Accept": "application/json"
                        }
    request = requests.get(requestUrl, headers=requestHeaders)
    response_dic = json.loads(request.content)
```

Is there a way I can look for using some kind of tag or event value?

All I´ve found is the keywords which I use here but they don´t seem to be very accurate as everyone is mentioning Coronavirus in one way or another and you end up with articles that only mention Coronavirus once in the whole article.

(for example: https://www.nytimes.com/2021/03/01/business/united-airlines-boeing-737-max.html).

I look to not use the query field with value "Coronavirus" as it also looks for words in the body and the same thing happens like before.

Comment: I recommend that you change your API key for the NYT API. You did leak private data. I help redact it in later version, but this is still stored in previous versions on SO.

Comment: I approved the edit. If it´s getting stored, should I repost then?

Comment: I don't think so. Just generate a new API key.

Comment: Ok will do, thank you

Comment: You need to define what "about coronavirus" actually means, then compute that criterion and threshold it. As it stands, I'm arguing that you want a tutorial on a research topic that's much too broad for SO.

Comment: Well I suppose I´m looking primarily for articles that are almost exclusively about COVID-19. What worries me is that using this request will get me articles that have little to do with COVID-19 and may add noise to my dataset.

A solution would be to get whatever I get from this request and then review each article manually to take out the weeds, but that would take me a long time so I asked just in case there was a way to better filter the results that I didn´t know.

Comment: The query is only as good as the data and so if the data needs wrangling, then wrangling it is. As far as removing noise, you might using use a set of common keywords to search for/filter for and rank based on that. I don't see the response so it's hard to see what metadata is supplied.

Comment: You might also look at `requests.get` `params` input. It will be easier to parse your URL with the search criteria. That very long list is less human readable.